# How to validate LDAP path against Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, active-directory

How to validate `LDAP` path? I have three `textboxes`, where I am allowing user to enter LDAP Path, username and password. I am able to validate username and password, but when it comes to validating LDAP path, it works initially, but after sometime, it allows invalid path as well.

Valid LDAP path:

> 192.168.12.12:565

Invalid LDAP path:

> gfg192.168.12.12:565fgfgf

and the user is able to get list of users using invalid path.

I have tried `LdapConnection`, using `Directory Entry` and using `PrincipalContext` :

```
LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(txtLDAPPath.Text.Trim());
NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(txtADUserName.Text.Trim(), password);
connection.Credential = credential;
connection.Bind();

using (DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry())
{
    entry.Username = txtADUserName.Text.Trim();
    entry.Password = password;
    entry.Path = txtLDAPPath.Text;
    DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
    search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))";
    object obj = entry.NativeObject;
    SearchResult resultCol = search.FindOne();
}


PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,"Domain");
bool Validate= ctx.ValidateCredentials(txtADUserName.Text, password);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you really expect the community to do without sharing your code? Please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have posted my code @uteist i have tried various ways mentioned but none of them validates LDAP Path.

Comment: With a quick look, I can tell that you don't actually use `LdapConnection` at all. You might find [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C) helpful for your AD app.

Comment: I have tried all these methods one by one but no one seems to be validating LDAP path.@uteist

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by validating LDAP path? What is your end goal?

Comment: I am allowing user to enter LDAP Path in a textbox and validate the same.@Burzum

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found out is via using System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne() method

```
        var paths = new[]
        {
            new { Path = "LDAP://192.168.1.1:389/OU=Users,OU=Administration,DC=ac-qa,DC=aaaa,DC=se", Filter = "(&(objectClass=user))" }, //OK! returns the first entry
            new { Path = "LDAP://192.168.1.1:389/OU=Users,OU=Administration,DC=ac-qa,DC=aaaa,DC=se", Filter = "this is wrong" }, //ERROR! the exeption message: "The this is wrong search filter is invalid."
            new { Path = "the wrong path", Filter = "(&(objectClass=user))" },      //ERROR! the exeption message: "Unspecified error"
            new { Path = "LDAP://192.168.1.1:389/OU=Test_OrgUnit,DC=ac-qa,DC=aaaa,DC=se", Filter = "(&(objectClass=user))" }, //OK! This is a valid path without any entry inside. result = null
        };

        foreach (var item in paths)
        {
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(item.Path, Login, Password);
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry, item.Filter);

            try
            {
                SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
```